# Extending a function in another .js file

Tags: javascript, extend

I have some js code in a file i can't touch because if i do so i'm breaking futur update of the core script...

```
!function($, mollify) {
mollify.view.MainViewFileView = function() {
    var that = this;
    this._currentFolder = false;
    this._currentFolderInfo = false;
    this._viewStyle = 0;
    this._selected = [];
    this._customFolderTypes = {};
    this._formatters = {
        byteSize : new mollify.ui.formatters.ByteSize(new mollify.ui.formatters.Number(2, false, mollify.ui.texts.get('decimalSeparator'))),
        timestamp : new mollify.ui.formatters.Timestamp(mollify.ui.texts.get('shortDateTimeFormat')),
        uploadSpeed : new mollify.ui.formatters.Number(1, mollify.ui.texts.get('dataRateKbps'), mollify.ui.texts.get('decimalSeparator'))
    };

    this._filelist = {
        columns : [],
        addColumn : function(c) {
            that._filelist.columns[c.id] = c;
        }
    };

    // spec
    this._filelist.addColumn({
        "id": "name",
        "title-key": "fileListColumnTitleName",
        "sort": function(i1, i2, sort, data) {
            return i1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(i2.name.toLowerCase()) * sort;
        },
        "content": function(item, data) {
            return item.name;
        }
    });...
```

now in another .js than i would load after the first one i would like to extend the first file with another "column" for example

```
????
// column 2
this._filelist.addColumn({
        "id": "newcolumn",
        "title-key": ... etc
```

How could i format this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the original function (short of replacing it with a new function), but what you can do is create a wrapper function around it. Something like:

```
mollify.view.MainViewFileViewModified = function() {
    var obj = new mollify.view.MainViewFileView();
    obj._filelist.addColumn(/* etc */);
    return obj;
};
```

Make sure this code executes after the code containing the original function.

Comment: thank you i'll try that but in this case do i need to call on init this new one "MainViewFileViewModified" in place of the "MainViewFileView" ? I so, i also can touch this... what i'm trying to achieve is a dead end no ?

Comment: You should be able to simply call `mollify.view.MainViewFileViewModified()`. I'm not sure what the rest of your question means.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite easy to modify the original function.  The poor option would be to simply overwrite it, but better would be to extend MainViewFileView's prototype.

```
mollify.view.MainViewFileView.prototype._filelist.addColumn = function({
    "id": "newcolumn",
    "title-key": ... etc
```

Comment: Also, it is unclear if you are asking if you can add/modify a method or simply push a new column onto the column stack, for the latter all you have do do is call `mollify.view.MainViewFileView._filelist.addColumn()`

Comment: yes sorry for that, i want to push a new column. I check your code right now